# php gd: create new image based on combine/join 3 images, and then rotate the new image

Tags: php, image, join, gd

Basically I have 3 png images. They have the same height and different width.

I want to create a new image on the fly, then join the 3 images (not merging, I want to respect the content of each image) and put them on the new image.

After that I wanto to rotate that new image.

I want to do it with php GD.

If someone can give me an idea, It would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new image in memory (setting width&height depending on how you want to join them), place the 3 images onto that image and save it.
This would be really simple with a library like [WideImage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: thanks a lot for answering. If you have the time to put a code to study it wouyld be great. We are in the middle of a project, and we don;t have the brains to go deep in documentation.

We have never used php gd or Wideimage.

Comment: it's really simple, just look at the examples on the link I gave you and you should be set.